# What all things do i have to change in my socket programs to make it work for computers on different networks

Tags: python, sockets, networking

If i have simple socket program with server and client programs to send a message how do I modify it to make it work for different networks. (say my friend and i want to send hi from our pcs)

The error message is:

> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

```
#Server
import socket

host = 'local host'
port = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(('', port))

s.listen(1)

c, addr = s.accept()

print("CONNECTION FROM:", str(addr))

c.send(b"Hi")

msg = "Bye.............."
c.send(msg.encode())

c.close()



#Client
import socket

host = 'local host'
port = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))

msg = s.recv(1024)

while msg:
    print('Recived:' + msg.decode())
    msg = s.recv(1024)

s.close()
```

Comment: This is too vague.  You need to make your question more specific.  A good way to do that is to show your coding attempt and tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: @RobertHarvey if this is the code how can I do it?

Comment: You said that you need to "make it work for different networks."  Is it working on one network but not another?  What do the two networks look like?  Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

this is the message I receive

Comment: To send to a server in another network, you need the *public* IP of the server, ensure firewalls on either computer aren't blocking the ports, and if you have a home router with a NAT configure port forwarding from the router to the server.

Comment: @MarkTolonen in my router's port forwarding option i need to enter internal IP, internal port and external port could you please tell me what to enter there. And what to enter in the IP and port of the programs. Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up port forwarding on your router.  Suppose your local system is the server serving on port 5000 and your friend is the client.

1. Open an Command Prompt on the server and run `ipconfig` to get your local IP address.  It is usually of the form 192.168.x.x but can vary.  It should also be available in your router's status page.
2. On your router, configure port forwarding for internal IP = local IP, interal port = 5000, external port = 5000.
3. Your router should also have your external Internet address on its status page.  You can also just google `whatsmyip`.  Give that IP and the external port number (5000) to your friend.  They use that to connect their client to your server.